# Network NAT and Bridge VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Please assist me in resolving the issue below.

We installed Rocky Linux VM on Windows 10

So we installed the Zabbix server on a VM and assigned it a static IP address because we needed access to it from another network (we are using a VPN connection to access all the servers on the same Zabbix IP address and it is working).

Now we set up two adapters in the VM: the first adapter attached to NAT, and the second adapter attached to Bridge. Here the VM has access to the internet and Google is pingable, but the Zabbix server IP is not pingable from another host.

if we change the adapter to the first adapter attached to  Bridge, the second adapter attached to NAT, here VM does not have access to the internet and google is not pingable but the Zabbix server IP is pingable from another host.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RABjW.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qpdK.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAmSQ.jpg)

Comment: What *"another host"* don't manage to ping to Zabbix you're refering to? The host machine? Better, try to add to your post the **configurations of the network interfaces**, as much the **VM running the Zabbix server** as the **host machine**.

Comment: The IPs used will also help.

Comment: “another host mean another pc with same ip range or different IP address connected vpn . I added screenshots of vm configuration and ip info machine Rocky Linux

Comment: Hello guys please any one can assistance regarding above issue. Thanks